# Magento admin: is it possible to add mass action with datepicker field?

Tags: php, magento, datepicker, admin

I'm trying to add a mass action to Customer grid to set a customer group (which will simulate subgroups) but the group assignment will have a limited time period.

I'm using Magento ver. 1.4.2.0.

In Customer grid definiton (in my class which extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Customer_Grid) I'm adding mass action like this:

```php
/*...*/

$this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('set_subgroup', array(
    'label'        => Mage::helper('customersubgroup')->__('Set Customer Subgroup'),
    'url'          => $this->getUrl('adminhtml/customersubgroup/massSetSubgroup'),
    'additional'   => array(
        'subgroup'    => array(
            'name'     => 'subgroup',
            'type'     => 'select',
            'class'    => 'required-entry',
            'label'    => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Group'),
            'values'   => $subgroups
        ),
        'valid_from'    => array(
            'name'     => 'valid_from',
            'type'     => 'date',
            'class'    => 'required-entry',
            'label'    => Mage::helper('customersubgroup')->__('Valid From'),
            'gmtoffset' => true,
            'format'    => '%d.%m.%Y'
        ),
        'valid_to'    => array(
            'name'     => 'valid_to',
            'type'     => 'date',
            'class'    => 'required-entry',
            'label'    => Mage::helper('customersubgroup')->__('Valid To'),
            'gmtoffset' => true,
            'format'    => '%d.%m.%Y'
        )
    )
));

/*...*/
```

There should be a customer group selectbox and two date fields as additional parameters of this mass action.

The date fields are rendered as text inputs but without a datepicker functionality (no calendar icon). Is it possible to add this functionality somehow?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I should probably shoot myself to the head right now. I've forgotten the `image` property in item definition:

```php
/*...*/

$this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('set_subgroup', array(
    'label'        => Mage::helper('customersubgroup')->__('Set Customer Subgroup'),
    'url'          => $this->getUrl('adminhtml/customersubgroup/massSetSubgroup'),
    'additional'   => array(
        'subgroup'    => array(
            'name'     => 'subgroup',
            'type'     => 'select',
            'class'    => 'required-entry',
            'label'    => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Group'),
            'values'   => $subgroups
        ),
        'valid_from'    => array(
            'name'     => 'valid_from',
            'type'     => 'date',
            'class'    => 'required-entry',
            'label'    => Mage::helper('customersubgroup')->__('Valid From'),
            'gmtoffset' => true,
            'image'    => '/skin/adminhtml/default/default/images/grid-cal.gif',
            'format'    => '%d.%m.%Y'
        ),
        'valid_to'    => array(
            'name'     => 'valid_to',
            'type'     => 'date',
            'class'    => 'required-entry',
            'label'    => Mage::helper('customersubgroup')->__('Valid To'),
            'gmtoffset' => true,
            'image'    => '/skin/adminhtml/default/default/images/grid-cal.gif',
            'format'    => '%d.%m.%Y'
        )
    )
));

/*...*/
```

So **YES, it is possible**.

Comment: i follow this code but after the ajax load grid the additional form are not showing any help?

Comment: Ajax loading probably changes the DOM of the entire table, filter form and mass action form, therefore the JavaScript handler for opening datepicker is no longer attached - original calendar icon with attached handler is replace with the new one after ajax. You have to manually init datepicker functionality after ajax load.